# How to get number of revision?

Tags: android, git, repository

How to get number of revision by using [`repo`](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the revisions, mentioned by [`repo init`](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#init) is the name of a tag:

```
-b: specify a revision, i.e., a particular manifest-branch.
```

You can see those (tags) listed in projects like [platform/development](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development) or [platform/build](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build).

However, as mentioned in "[`repo init` a particular commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10820464/6309)", the -b option doesn't take a SHA1:

> So, the correct way of obtaining the sources of the repository for the particular build is to obtain it's manifest.
>   I.e., manifest, that will contain SHA's (or tags, which are practically the same, if they are present) instead of branch names

Comment: I don't uderstand. How i can see in what revision now i worked? I mean whole repo revision nor SHA1 of 1 of git repositories.

Comment: @Pepelac what command did you type to initialize your repo environment? (`repo init`)

Comment: @Pepelac I understand it is that command (that you use), but I would like to know the exact parameters you added with that command. It could help determining the revisions you are using. For all the submodules fetch with that repo, the exact revisions are in the `.repo/manifests/default.xml` (as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818758/repo-init-a-particular-commit/10820464#10820464)

Comment: @Pepelac then you should see a `.repo/manifests/default.xml`. In it are all the revisions used for the various git submodules.

Comment: But there is no SHA sum or numbers of revisions.

Comment: That's why I linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818758/repo-init-a-particular-commit/10820464#10820464: it describes how the manifest will contains the tags (ie "named SHA1") for each submodules.