# build a particular version of cyanogenmod (namely, 9.0.0-galaxys2)

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I want to build cyanogenmod 9.0.0 for samsung galaxy s2.
I have read http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_i9100 and compiled the stuff successfully.
But what has been built is cm-11, while I need 9.0.0. (I'm hunting a bug in the code written by another person, and I need this version to understand what is going on.)

The command

```
$ repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-9.0.0
```

breaks with

```
error: in `init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git --repo-url=https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo --repo-branch=stable`: revision refs/heads/master in manifests not found
```

but the help says that `-b` specifies the ***manifest*** branch or revision, so unless the description is misleading it should be possible to use the latest manifest and later checkout the necessary version.

So I used the command

```
$ repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-11.0
```

But now I get:

```
$ repo branch
   (no branches)
$ repo branches
   (no branches)
```

For comparison, in the directory where cm-11 has been built, I also get `(no branches)`.

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/10820464/755804
I read that I should use a manifest file specific to the build in question, but where/how do I get it? (The file lists a revision for each of the git repositories in the repo tree; obtaining this list manually would be an odious task, there should be a script able to do this. Or maybe the files to repeat each build are stored somewhere and I just don't know where?)

So: ***How do I check out a particular revision of Cyanogenmod source?*** (In particular, cm-9.0.0-galaxys2?)

**UPDATE**

Found 
`repo help forall` -- *run a shell command in each project.* ***BUT*** `repo forall -c 'git branch'` shows a `(no branch)` for each project. UPD: because it should be `repo forall -c git branch -a`, but the set of shown branches will depend on the parameter passed with the `-b` key to `repo init`.

**UPDATE 2**

The answer below shows how to checkout the sources. The next step is to run `breakfast i9100` (what a stupid non-descriptive name!) Unfortunately, it does not work because since some moment in the past github api began to require application authentication (and the no-auth quote is not enough for `breakfast`). Thus, *a change in github access policy has broken a version control script and in fact has turned the commit history into useless old rubbish: one cannot rebuild the old version. I would say, it's an epic fail of the version control systems in general: it turned out that a version control system cannot replace a directory with zipped copies of the source tree. (And the amount of sub-projects and the use of a 3rd-party script to manage them are key components in that failure.)*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure one can build it, but this is how one can at least retrieve the 9.0.0 sources.

First, you do

```
repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-9.0.0
repo sync
```

and you get an error message like

```
Syncing work tree:  58% (144/248)  error: in `sync`: revision refs/heads/cm-9.0.0 in CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base not found
```

I have to note that if it was `cm-9.1.0`, this would succeed.

Now, let us mend the errors that appear:

**for each** error like

```
error: in `sync`: revision refs/heads/cm-9.0.0 in CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings not found
```

**do**

1. the link `.repo/manifest.xml` points to `.repo/manifests/default.xml`;
2. find "android_packages_apps_Settings" in that file, something like:
   `<project path="packages/apps/Settings" name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings"/>`
3. add `revision="cm-9.1.0"`, it then will look like `<project path="packages/apps/Settings" name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings" revision="cm-9.1.0"/>`
4. manually delete the directory specified as the path, namely `packages/apps/Settings` in this example
5. run `repo sync` again

***You will get a mix of 9.0.0 and 9.1.0 sources; for the most part, it will be 9.0.0.***

Now, `cd vendor/cm; ./get-prebuilts` will fail, but since it says

```
# Get Android Terminal Emulator (we use a prebuilt so it can update from the Market)
```

it is ok to use `./get-prebuilts` from cm-11, which will succeed.