# repo override remote URL of the element project without change

Tags: repo

Is any repo sync option could override the **remote URL** by specified project
for example, I have locally kernel git repository and some hotfix, driver porting whatever
so I want to run such fake command without modified **.repo/manifect.xml**

> repo sync --project-remote-url=git://my.server.ip/kernel.git

Answer (score 3):

Try with [local-manifests](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md#local-manifests).

The local manifests will be combined with the default.xml. And you can [adding or replacing projects](https://github.com/LocalManifestsDemo/local_manifests) in default.xml.

For example:

```
<manifest>
    <!-- add github as a new remote source -->
    <remote name="github" fetch="git://github.com" />

    <!-- remove project in default.xml -->
    <remove-project name="platform/bootable/recovery" />
  
    <!-- replace with new remote github -->
    <project path="bootable/recovery" name="CyanogenMod/android_bootable_recovery" remote="github" revision="cm-10.1" />

    <!-- add new project -->
    <project path="external/busybox" name="CyanogenMod/android_external_busybox" remote="github" revision="cm-10.1" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: This looks like a really rough way to do it if you have a manifest with more than a few projects.  I'm thinking an approach using included manifests joined in an alternative composite manifest would work.